# Deleting all paths != String1 or String2

Tags: javascript, if-statement, photoshop, photoshop-script

I'm not quite sure how to phrase the syntax for this. Ultimately I want to delete all path in a document that don't have the name Ex1 or Ex2 or Ex3.

This is what I have so far

```
deletepaths();

function deletepaths() {
    if (!documents.length) return;
    var doc = activeDocument;
    for (var a = doc.pathItems.length - 1; a > -1; a--) {
        if (doc.pathItems[a].name == "Ex1") {
            return true;
        }
        if
        else(doc.pathItems[a].name == "Ex2") {
            return true;
        } else doc.pathItems[a].remove();
    }
}
```

Here is another script I was using prior that works, but doesn't allow me to exlude multiple "path" names

```js
#target Photoshop
main();
function main(){
if(!documents.length) return;
var doc = activeDocument;
for(var a = doc.pathItems.length-1;a>-1;a--){
if(doc.pathItems[a].name  != "Ex1") doc.pathItems[a].remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```js
function deletepaths() {
    if (!documents.length) return;
    var doc = activeDocument;
    for (var a = doc.pathItems.length - 1; a > -1; a--) {
        if (!doc.pathItems[a].name.match(/^Ex[1-3]$/)) {
            doc.pathItems.splice(a,1);
        }
    }
}

//Testing
var documents = [{}, {}],
    activeDocument = {"pathItems": [{name: "Ex1"}, {name: "Ex2"}, {name: "Someothername"}, {name: "Exasd1"}, {name: "asdEx1"}, {name: "Ex2"}, {name: "Ex3"}, {name: "Ex2"}, {name: "Exasd1"}, {name: "Exasd1"}, ]};
deletepaths();
                                    
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
activeDocument.pathItems.forEach(function(a,b,c){
    body.innerHTML += a.name + "<br>";    
});
```

Comment: can you break this down a little for me? I'm not quite sure how to amend this so it'll work as a photoshop script

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, formatting your code in a more readable fashion can help diagnose the issue.

This function approaches the problem in a slightly different manner -- we keep an array of names that we want to save, and if the path's name isn't in that array, then we call `.remove()` on it.

I'm also returning a `boolean` (in the event that the element tied to your `documents` variable doesn't exist) so that the function feeds something useful back to you, instead of returning `undefined`.

I'm not familiar with the library you're using, but try this out. I'm happy to work with you to get a solution, just leave a comment on this answer.

**Use this function:**

```
function deletepaths()
{
  if (!documents.length) return false;

  var doc = activeDocument;
  var save = ["Ex1", "Ex2", "Ex3"];

  for (var x = 0; x < doc.pathItems.length; x++)
  {
    if (save.indexOf(doc.pathItems[x].name) == -1)
    {
      doc.pathItems[x].remove();
    }
  }
}
```

**Working Example:**

http://codepen.io/bddenhartog/pen/VLReKa
*Note that the code in the pen has been modified to accommodate the example.*

Comment: hmm, doesn't seem to be working. This is the library documentation: http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop_scriptref_js.pdf

Comment: I added another comment to original post

Comment: I updated my answer. If it works for you, please remember to mark it as the answer for future readers. If it doesn't work for you, let me know what kind of output you're getting.

Comment: unfortunately, I get an error: save.indexOf is not a function, but if I type this in via the ExtendScript Toolkit app, I get a code hint saying: "String.indexOf(searchValue, offset): Returns the index within the string of the first occurrence of the specified string, starting the search at fromIndex if provided

Comment: It looks like indexOf, then, is a string method, not an array method as is working in my example. I'm in class right now, but will look over the documentation later today and see if I can figure this out for you.

Comment: I came accross this and added the poly fill to the beginning of the script. The script now runs, but doesn't delete all extra paths outside of the 2 I want to keep. One or more paths will still stick around after I run the script. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: To Clarify, It'll now delete the first != occurance and then every other one after that.

Comment: Got it to work by using for(var a = doc.pathItems.length-1;a>-1;a--)